# Propositional Logic Problem - Identify the Truth Teller, the Liar and the unpredictable

Tags: logic

The problem says:

A tourist is enjoying afternoon refreshment in a local pub in England when the bartender 
says to him: Do you see those three men over there? One is Mr. X who always tells the 
truth, another is Mr.Y who always lies and the third is Mr.Z who sometimes tells the truth 
and sometimes lies, that is Mr.Z answers yes or no at random without regard to the 
question. You may ask them three yes or no questions always indicating which man 
should answer. If after asking these three questions, you correctly identify who are Mr.X, Mr. Y and Mr. 
Z, they will buy you a drink. What yes or no questions should the thirsty tourist ask?

How to go about this problem and other similar problems with propositional logic?

Comment: This is The Hardest Logic Puzzle Ever. [No, seriously.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hardest_Logic_Puzzle_Ever)

Comment: I would ask one question: Are you sitting?

Comment: All of them are Mr. Z, including the bartender. That jerk.

Comment: @DavidH Not quite; that version has the added difficulty of the responses being in an unknown language (you don't know which of 'da' and 'ja' mean 'yes' and 'no'), and the random-answerer behaves slightly differently in Boolos's version.

Comment: @dbmag9 it seemw like Boolos was a big troll - 'da' means 'yes' in Russian and 'ja' means 'yes' in a lot of Germanic languages :)

Comment: @user132181 I don't think that counts as trolling so much as just using useful words - the point of the puzzle is that in the gods' language one means 'yes' and the other 'no'.

Comment: Hmmm ... if I asked Mr. X what Mr. Z would say if I asked him some question, what would Mr. X answer?

Comment: @ David H I think the [XKCD logic puzle](https://xkcd.com/246/) is harder!

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Would it be cheating to ask them a paradox? E.g. "does the set that contains all the sets that do not contain themselves contain itself?" This would be an effective way of identifying the truth teller, I think, since despite it being a yes or no question he would have to answer with "it is a paradox".

Answer (score 3):

A similar puzzle without the random option: You are in the catacombs, there are 2 guards by a fork in the tunnel and you have been told that one always lies and the other never does. The question you can ask is 'which way would the other guard tell me to go?' and go the opposite way.

With the addition of the random Mr Z*, the best you can do is to spend 2 questions working out who is Mr Z, then ask one of the other two the question from above.

* Read the Hardest Logic Puzzle Ever for nuance on whether the random actor randomly lies or randomly answers yes or no, because the latter (as seems to be the case here) is harder.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is to figure out the possible arrangements of people and properties, and then draw a table of what they would answer to various questions in each arrangement.after some trial and error you'll develop an intuition for the kind of questions that give you useful results.

Note that as posed there are some questions some men can't answer (specifically, neither the truth-teller nor the liar knows what the random-answerer will say in response to any question). I think Boolos describes this as a head-exploding outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I ask X: I give you 2 statements is exactly one of them true?" The statements are

1. Do you always speak the truth?
2. Does Y tell truth and lie randomly?"

Now have a close look if he says YES it can have 3 possible cases.

1. X tells the truth always thats the only true statement so B is the liar.
2. X answers my question randomly.
3. X is a liar so both statements are false so Y is not a random person.

So what is common here is Y is not the random person.
A similar analysis on X answering NO we assure us that Z is not a random person. So with one question exhausted we have a person who we know is not random.
So we go to that person and ask him an universal truth like "does sun rise in the east?" YES or NO will confirm that he is truthful or liar respectively. 
Suppose here we arrive at the fact that Y is truthful, so we go on to ask him "Does X always lie?" So we know the status of X,Z immediately based on the answer. The same analysis can be done in any case and we will recognise X,Y,Z and enjoy our drink.

Answer (score 0):

The tourist may first ask : 'Are you present in a pub right now?' If the liar is answering, he will say 'no', then the tourist can eliminate the liar (Mr.Y). But if a person answers 'Yes', then that person may be a truth teller (Mr.X) or a random answering person (Mr.Z). To eliminate a liar, the tourist shoots the same question to some other person. If the answer comes 'Yes' , then the person to whom he hasn't asked any question yet is a liar, i.e Mr.Y. If answer comes back 'No', then he is liar.

Now after 2 question , we are left with a two unknown person, a truth teller and a random answering person. How to proceed further?

Comment: If the first person says "No", they may be a liar, or a random person.

Answer (score 0):

**If the three men know one another** and if they are sitting or standing together at one place, the tourist can identify them with one question to all the three men. (But here I can't consider good manners.)

1. If Mr X is not sure of something, he will say "Not sure".
2. If Mr Y is not sure of something, he will keep mum about it because, if he will say "Yes/No", sometimes it will become a truth. "Not sure/I don't know/I can't say"--all these are certainly truths. Since he is a liar he can never say so.
3. But Mr Z will always say "Yes/No".

You may ask them about any fact/truth (which all the three men are familiar with) according to the situation. But the questions must be the same and the right answers must be "Yes/No" only.

Approach each man and ask pointing to the other two about both of their replies if he asked them whether they are policemen?"

**Since this question is about two persons, he must get two answers from each person**. But Mr Y will be compelled to reply to one part only.

See the table given below

Conclusion (for a verification):

*He who says "Not sure" (about one person), is Mr X.*

*He who keeps mum in the case of one person, is Mr Y.*

*He who says "Yes" and/or "No" only, is Mr Z.*

**For analysis,** let us consider this question (to each man).   **"would you tell me both of their replies if I asked them whether they are policemen?"**

Suppose this question has two right answers--Yes/No.

Then each man will **quote the possible responses** of the other two men. So, response of the speaker about himself is not applicable. [See the table.]

[image]

Even though the right answer is mixed (Yes & No) there won't be any problem. E.g.: Mr X is a policeman and Mr Y and Mr Z are not.

If the tourist could identify the two men with two questions, he doesn't need to ask the third man (If he repeats the question).

Now, let us combine the three columns (2,3 & 4) and find out the solution.

For this, the tourist can ask this question:   **"Will both of them say "Yes" if I asked them whether they are policemen?"**

This "Yes/No" question will give three types of outputs.

[image]

Here the (Final) conclusion is this: [See the first two tables also]

*He who says "Not sure", is Mr X.*  [Reason: Since Mr Z's response is "Not sure"]

*He who keeps mum, is Mr Y.*  [Reason: To avoid saying the truth]

*He who says "Yes/No", is Mr Z.*  [Reason: He always says Yes/No]

> How to go about this problem and other similar problems with
>   propositional logic?

Other similar problems can be solved like this. As given above, combine row-wise and column-wise and make **different outputs** according to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a possibility of certainty we need not depend on probability.  That is not a good logic.  So, there is not much complication as almost all of us think.

According to the question the tourist will get a maximum of 2 Yes-answers or 2 No-answers to a Yes-question. So, if he got 2 such answers from first two questions he can ask the third question to one of the first two men again.

If the three men don't know one another, the tourist doesn't need to ask anything to the third man in two cases. He can identify all men by the third question.  But third question must always be an **unpredictable Ye/No question**.  E.g.: "Will I get a drink from you after some time?" Since this is an unpredictable question X and Y won't say "Yes/No"; but Z will.

So, the first two questions may be the same (The right answer must always be "Yes"): "Is today a Sunday?" (If it was a Sunday)
The third question: "Will I get a drink from you after some time?"

The responses are given as a table below.  **Here in the first two cases in the following table, the third question is again to the 1st Man.** But in the other 4 cases, the third question is to the 3rd Man.

Here I didn't ask anything to the 3rd Man if he got 2 Yes-answers or 2 No-answers. (See cases 1 & 2)

I have mentioned the order of the men who were identified as (decision 1)-- D1, D2 & D3. [i.e, D1 was identified first, D2 second and D3 third.]
Except in Cases 1&2 D2 & D3 are interchangeable [i.e., the 3rd decision can be taken as the 2nd decision. Answers will not change.].

[image]

N.B: $ The person who the first question was asked in each case.

You can find out the answer using a 'No-question' instead of my 'Yes-question'(Is today a Sunday?).

But the order of Men given in the table above will change.